# Firestore - how to query multiple fields to single array

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents of type `Object`. Each `Object` has the following fields, `admin`, `team` and `invited`.

Admin contains a single string of the users uid.

Team and Invited fields are an array containing user uid's.

Currently I query all documents with where the admin field isEqual to the currentUser.uid like so;

```
if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    db.collection("objects")
        .whereField("admin", isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)

        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents for admin")
            return
        }

        self.Objects = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Object? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Object.self)
        }

    }
}
```

How can I from here query the other fields and store in a single array to use as a single reference? I have tried the following,

Multiple comqueries,

```
if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    db.collection("objects")
        .whereField("admin", isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
        .whereField("invited", arrayContainsAny: [currentUser.email!])
        .whereField("team", arrayContainsAny: [currentUser.uid])

        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents for admin")
            return
        }

        self.Objects = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Object? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Object.self)
        }

    }
}
```

However this doesn't work, also tried multiple document fetches to a single array like so,

```
if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    db.collection("objects")
        .whereField("admin", isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)

        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents for admin")
            return
        }

        self.Objects = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Object? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Object.self)
        }

    }
}


if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    db.collection("objects")
        .whereField("invited", arrayContainsAny: [currentUser.email!])

        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents for admin")
            return
        }

        let objects2 = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Object? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Object.self)
        }

        self.objects.append(contentsOf: objects2)

    }
}
```

Comment: " How can I from here query the other fields and store in a single array to use as a single reference "
Maybe you can clarify this a little bit more? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I believe once you have queried all the documents at that point you can just access the object property you need